# I need help getting on('focus') to work with my website search box

Tags: jquery

I'm setting up a new website for internal work use only and I need the product search to to clear the text once I click back on the box. I have looked at lots of solutions but cant seem to get it working. I would like to use jQuery to solve this issue. I found something on called 'clear input field on focus'. I need to adjust the code below but I really don't know what to do

Please see attached picture to see the class

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $usernameField = $('#username'),
    defaultValue = $usernameField.data('default-value');

  $usernameField.on('focus', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() == defaultValue)
      $this.val('');
  });

  $usernameField.on('focusout', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().trim() == '')
      $this.val(defaultValue);
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Why not clear the field on('click',function()

Comment: The element in the picture doesn't have the `id` of `username`, nor does it have a `data-default-value` attribute. However if all you want to do is clear the box when it has focus, just use `$(this).val('')` with no other conditional logic.

Comment: Looks like you only try to empty it if it has the default value which it won't have after you search for something.

Comment: can anyone show me what i should use and how i can use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help Rory, i have finally figured out how to word the jQuery below is what i done to sort it

```
    jQuery( function($) {
    $('.input-text').click(function() {
    $(this).val('');
   });
  });
```